# Android Studio can't find opencv modules, but compiles ok

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

My project compiles fine, but Android Studio panics because it thinks it can't find opencv's modules:

[image]
[image]

OpenCV is included as a separate module, and it's listed as a dependency. As far as I can tell it's all set up fine. OpenCV's `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 2480
        versionName "2.4.8"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what's going on? I'm not too bugged as I said, it compiles and runs absolutely fine. It is very annoying though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally cracked this one. Following some online guides (I can't remember now which one), I'd installed opencv into `/libraries/opencv/` in my project. The problem was that the code was in the directory `./src/main/java/org/opencv/[module]`, and this was causing classpath problems.

To solve the problem, I moved `./src/main/java/org` to `./src/org`. I did this in my file manager, not in Android Studio, and then rebuilt the project.

The project compiles fine, and all the errors are gone.